# How to send an IM message in vLine

Tags: vline

To be able to chat with someone by sending the vLine `im`-type messages, you don’t need to have a `mediaSession` established with the remote user first, correct? All you need is the remote person’s ID and you can send them message, correct?

Or not? And if not, how do you do send an IM with vLine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. You do not need to have a [`mediaSession`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.MediaSession) in order to send an IM. The `vline.MediaSession` is only used for audio and/or video sessions.

To send an IM, you just need to have the [`vline.Person`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Person) object representing the person that you want to send the message to. You can then call [`postMessage`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Channel#postMessage) or [`publishMessage`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Channel#publishMessage) to send the IM, with the difference between the two being that [`postMessage`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Channel#postMessage) saves the IM history, while [`publishMessage`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Channel#publishMessage) does not.

Also, you can send IMs to a user even if that user is not online and use the [`Person.getUnreadCount`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Channel#getUnreadCount) API to keep track of the number of unread messages from a specific `Person`.

Comment: Great. Thanks very much for confirming!